# magento transactional email for custom module

Tags: magento, email, variables, transactional

Hi I have a custom Module built that sends an email when certain order statues are being created.

I have an observer that hooks into sales_order_place_after and my order object sinde observer.php is

```
   public function getOrderStatus($observer)
 {
   $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
   $status = $order->getStatus();
   $enabled = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_ENABLE);
   if($enabled == 1){
       if($status  === "fraud")
       {
        $this->sendFraudEmail($observer);
       }
 }
```

}

but inside the transactional emails {{var order.increment_id}} is not working, even though in the observer I have : $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

what am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your full code specifically the `sendFraudEmail()` method you are calling. You need to parse through an array of the objects you wish to use in the transactional email.

Comment: can you give me a sample of how the array I am passing through should look like?

Comment: thanks for setting me on the right tracks, I missed the array inside send transactional()  like this:

       ->sendTransactional(
                  /* ... ... .. ..  */
                    array(
                        'order'             => $this->getOrder(),

Answer (score 1):

Normally to send a custom transactional email you do something like the following;

```
$templateId = 16;

$sender  = array(
    'name' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()),
    'email' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
);

$vars = array('order' => $observer->getEvent()->getOrder());

Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $customerEmail, $customerName, $vars, $storeId);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the issue.